# EmberJS - Unit testing a component

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to writing unit tests.

I am trying to write a unit test for a tooltip Ember component. The usage pattern is

```
<div id="parent"> I have a tooltip</div>
{{tooltip-comp}}
    tooltip content
{{/tooltip-comp}}
```

I am trying to check that clicking the parent div (with id parent), makes the 'isVisible' property true for the component.

Do I need to somehow insert a parent to DOM to be able to do this?

I am using Ember CLI.

Comment: Is the action which receives the click on the parent part of the component, or is is on a controller (or route)? That changes how you test it. If the action isn't on the component, testing that the click changes the property is an integration test. You could test the rendered state of the component, then do what the action does and test the new rendered state of the component, perhaps.